# How to run a code after timer.performWithDelay ? - Corona Sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In this script:

```
function moveB()
    if B then   
        B.x = B.x + 4
    end
end
function clickA()
    A.isVisible = false
    B.isVisible = true
    if fastSquare then
        B.x, B.y = A.x, A.y
        timer.performWithDelay(20, moveB, 5)
        A.isVisible = true
        B.isVisible = false
    end
end
A:addEventListener("tap", clickA)
```

,  I want this code:

```
A.isVisible = true
B.isVisible = false
```

to run after `timer.performWithDelay()` has call function moveB() 5 times but they run the same time even if i have put `A.isVisible = false  B.isVisible = true` below `timer.performWithDelay()`.

Comment: you do run the code after timer.performWithDelay has completed. I think you misunderstand what this function does. Please refer to the Corona manual

Answer (score 0):

```
timer.performWithDelay(20, moveB, 5)
```

Says: after 20ms call moveB, do this 5 times in total.

As this is just registering the timed call of moveB anything that comes after that line is executed immediately.

As you already set those properties befor the if statement there is no need to do it inside the if statement again. It has no effect.

```
 A.isVisible = false
    B.isVisible = true
    if fastSquare then
        B.x, B.y = A.x, A.y
        timer.performWithDelay(20, moveB, 5)
        A.isVisible = false -- obsolete
        B.isVisible = true -- obsolete
    end
```

Comment: Got the solution, tk.